# html amp button disable

Tags: html, google-chrome, amp-html

I am trying to implement a stepper sliding form in html-amp. I have a page where I want to implement button which should enable when some input is given in the input firstname. My button remains disabled, I have tried different ways to implement, but have been unsuccessful.
I would like to implement something like disable[disabled] = "!firstname", where if the condition satisfied firstname is null, then the button remains disable.

Also, I have worked out that this code works perfectly when used in microsoft edge, and also the editor provided by the stackexchange itself. So, it is getting trickier as it is not just some logical error to be fixed.

```html
<!---{
  "preview": "default",
  "default": "preview"
  }--->
<!--
  ## Introduction
  This sample demonstrates different approaches for how to implement a multi-step flow in AMP. These could 
  be used for checkout flows, sign-ups or surveys.
-->
<!-- -->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="<%host%>/../dynamic_amp/multi_page_flow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!-- We use `amp-bind` to coordinate the page transitions... -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <!-- ... and `amp-selector` for implementing a simple survey. -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
 
  
<style amp-custom>
/* Sliding Stepper */
.stepper.sliding {position: relative;overflow-x: hidden;height: 300px;max-width: 420px;margin: 1rem auto;}
.stepper.sliding .page {background-color: "#ffffff";position: absolute;display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: flex-start;width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 16px;transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.3, 1);}
.stepper.sliding .page.active {transform: translateX(0%);pointer-events: auto;}
.stepper.sliding .page:not(.active) {opacity: 0.5;pointer-events: none;}
.stepper.sliding .page.next {transform: translateX(100%);}
.stepper.sliding .page.previous {transform: translateX(-100%);}
.stepper.sliding .back {position: relative;height: 32px;width: 100%;max-width: 300px;cursor: pointer;line-height: 32px;border: none;background: none;text-align: left;padding: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;}
.stepper.sliding .back:after {content: "";position: absolute;top: 10px;right: 3px;border: solid black;border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;display: inline-block;padding: 3px;transform: rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);}

/* Survey styling */

amp-selector.poll [option][selected] {outline: none;}
amp-selector.poll [option] {display: flex;align-items: center;}
amp-selector.poll [option]:before {transition: background 0.25s ease-in-out;content: "";display: inline-block;width: 16px;height: 16px;margin: 8px;border-radius: 100%;border: solid 1px #b60845;font-size: 14px;line-height: 16px;}
amp-selector.poll [option][selected]:before {text-align: center;content: "✓";color: white;background: #b60845;}
amp-selector.poll [option][selected]:focus {outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;}

.top_slogan{ text-align:center; color:#555; font-size:30px;   padding: 15px 10px; line-height:40px;  clear:both;}
#abe-preview {display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;justify-content: center;width: 100%;min-height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));}
.main_content_small{max-width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 2em;background-color: #e8e8e8;border: 20px solid #fff;}

.row {zoom: 1;}
.row:before,
.row:after {content: "";display: table;}
.row:after {clear: both;}

.hcolor{ color: #f98740;}

.input-group {margin-bottom: 1em;zoom: 1;}
.input-group:before,
.input-group:after {content: "";display: table;}
.input-group:after {clear: both;}
.input-group-icon {position: relative;}
.input-group-icon input {padding-left: 4.4em;}
.input-group-icon .input-icon {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 3.4em;height: 3.4em;line-height: 3.4em;text-align: center;pointer-events: none;}
.input-group-icon .input-icon:after {position: absolute;top: 0.6em;bottom: 0.6em;left: 3.4em;display: block;border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;content: "";-webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;}
.input-group-icon .input-icon i {-webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;}

.col-half {padding-right: 10px;float: left;width: 50%;}
.col-half:last-of-type {padding-right: 0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .col-half {width: 100%;padding-right: 0;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body style = "background-color:#f9f7f7">
  <div class="top_slogan"><h1>Fill in Contract</h1></div>
  <div class = "main_content_small">
    <div class="stepper sliding page">
      <section class="page active" 
             [class]="slidingStepperPage > 0 ? 'page previous' : 'page active'"> 
        <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3 mt3">
          <div class="row">
            <h3 class="hcolor">Personaldaten</h3>
            <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
              <div class="col-half">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Vorname *" required="required" on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ disable: false })">
                <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "input-group">
          <button on="tap:AMP.pushState({ slidingStepperPage: slidingStepperPage + 1 })"
              class="align-self-end ampstart-btn ampstart-btn-secondary caps"
              disabled [disabled]="disable">next</button>
        </div>    
      </section>
      <section class="page next" 
             [class]="slidingStepperPage < 1 ? 'page next' : 
             (slidingStepperPage > 1 ? 'page previous' : 'page active')"> 
        <h3>Sign in</h3>
        <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3 mt3">
          <input type="email" value="" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="id1" class="block border-none p0 m0" placeholder="Enter your Email"
                    on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ email: event.value })">
          <label for="ip1" class="absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0" aria-hidden="true">
          Enter your Email
          </label>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
 </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to small changes only

```
on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ disable: false })"
```

to

```
on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ disable: event.value!='' ? false : true })"
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="<%host%>/../dynamic_amp/multi_page_flow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!-- We use `amp-bind` to coordinate the page transitions... -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <!-- ... and `amp-selector` for implementing a simple survey. -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
 
  
<style amp-custom>
/* Sliding Stepper */
.stepper.sliding {position: relative;overflow-x: hidden;height: 300px;max-width: 420px;margin: 1rem auto;}
.stepper.sliding .page {background-color: "#ffffff";position: absolute;display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: flex-start;width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 16px;transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.3, 1);}
.stepper.sliding .page.active {transform: translateX(0%);pointer-events: auto;}
.stepper.sliding .page:not(.active) {opacity: 0.5;pointer-events: none;}
.stepper.sliding .page.next {transform: translateX(100%);}
.stepper.sliding .page.previous {transform: translateX(-100%);}
.stepper.sliding .back {position: relative;height: 32px;width: 100%;max-width: 300px;cursor: pointer;line-height: 32px;border: none;background: none;text-align: left;padding: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;}
.stepper.sliding .back:after {content: "";position: absolute;top: 10px;right: 3px;border: solid black;border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;display: inline-block;padding: 3px;transform: rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);}

/* Survey styling */

amp-selector.poll [option][selected] {outline: none;}
amp-selector.poll [option] {display: flex;align-items: center;}
amp-selector.poll [option]:before {transition: background 0.25s ease-in-out;content: "";display: inline-block;width: 16px;height: 16px;margin: 8px;border-radius: 100%;border: solid 1px #b60845;font-size: 14px;line-height: 16px;}
amp-selector.poll [option][selected]:before {text-align: center;content: "✓";color: white;background: #b60845;}
amp-selector.poll [option][selected]:focus {outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;}

.top_slogan{ text-align:center; color:#555; font-size:30px;   padding: 15px 10px; line-height:40px;  clear:both;}
#abe-preview {display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;justify-content: center;width: 100%;min-height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));}
.main_content_small{max-width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 2em;background-color: #e8e8e8;border: 20px solid #fff;}

.row {zoom: 1;}
.row:before,
.row:after {content: "";display: table;}
.row:after {clear: both;}

.hcolor{ color: #f98740;}

.input-group {margin-bottom: 1em;zoom: 1;}
.input-group:before,
.input-group:after {content: "";display: table;}
.input-group:after {clear: both;}
.input-group-icon {position: relative;}
.input-group-icon input {padding-left: 4.4em;}
.input-group-icon .input-icon {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 3.4em;height: 3.4em;line-height: 3.4em;text-align: center;pointer-events: none;}
.input-group-icon .input-icon:after {position: absolute;top: 0.6em;bottom: 0.6em;left: 3.4em;display: block;border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;content: "";-webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;}
.input-group-icon .input-icon i {-webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;-o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;}

.col-half {padding-right: 10px;float: left;width: 50%;}
.col-half:last-of-type {padding-right: 0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .col-half {width: 100%;padding-right: 0;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body style = "background-color:#f9f7f7">
  <div class="top_slogan"><h1>Fill in Contract</h1></div>
  <div class = "main_content_small">
    <div class="stepper sliding page">
      <section class="page active" 
             [class]="slidingStepperPage > 0 ? 'page previous' : 'page active'"> 
        <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3 mt3">
          <div class="row">
            <h3 class="hcolor">Personaldaten</h3>
            <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
              <div class="col-half">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Vorname *" required="required" on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ disable: event.value!='' ? false : true })">
                <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "input-group">
          <button on="tap:AMP.pushState({ slidingStepperPage: slidingStepperPage + 1 })"
              class="align-self-end ampstart-btn ampstart-btn-secondary caps"
              disabled [disabled]="disable">next</button>
        </div>    
      </section>
      <section class="page next" 
             [class]="slidingStepperPage < 1 ? 'page next' : 
             (slidingStepperPage > 1 ? 'page previous' : 'page active')"> 
        <h3>Sign in</h3>
        <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3 mt3">
          <input type="email" value="" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="id1" class="block border-none p0 m0" placeholder="Enter your Email"
                    on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ email: event.value })">
          <label for="ip1" class="absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0" aria-hidden="true">
          Enter your Email
          </label>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
 </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried using your file, and it works perfectly. But, I have tried copying my whole code in a new file and it works perfectly. So, in the given scenario both will work perfectly, mine work with less hassle. 
I still think the issue is with chrome's disabilities with local files. I tried Ctrl+F5 but still it somehow takes lot of time to load and also it doesn't respond to changes made in the file. I had to copy the whole code in a new file to make it work.

Comment: Due to google cache, you need to clear the amp google cache. Accept the answer so it's help community member.